# How to compute a spatial distance matrix from a given value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance, scipy-spatial

I've been looking for a way to (efficiently) compute a distance matrix from a target value and an input matrix.

If you consider an input array as:

```
[0 0 1 2 5 2 1]  
[0 0 2 3 5 2 1]  
[0 1 1 2 5 4 1]  
[1 1 1 2 5 4 0]
```

Ho do you compute the spatial distance matrix associated to the target value 0?

i.e. what is the distance from each pixel to the closest 0 value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html). It operates on a binary array and computes euclidean distances on each `TRUE` position to the nearest background `FALSE` position. In our case, since we want to find out distances from nearest 0s, so the background is `0`. Now, under the hoods, it converts the input to a binary array assuming 0 as the background, so we can just use it with the default parameters. Hence, it would be as simple as -

```
In [179]: a
Out[179]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0]])

In [180]: from scipy import ndimage

In [181]: ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a)
Out[181]: 
array([[0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 2.  , 3.  , 3.16, 3.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 2.  , 2.83, 2.24, 2.  ],
       [0.  , 1.  , 1.41, 2.24, 2.24, 1.41, 1.  ],
       [1.  , 1.41, 2.24, 2.83, 2.  , 1.  , 0.  ]])
```

**Solving for generic case**

Now, let's say we want to find out distances from nearest `1s`, then it would be -

```
In [183]: background = 1 # element from which distances are to be computed

# compare this with original array, a to verify
In [184]: ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a!=background)
Out[184]: 
array([[2.  , 1.  , 0.  , 1.  , 2.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
       [1.41, 1.  , 1.  , 1.41, 2.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
       [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 2.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 2.  , 1.41, 1.  ]])
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for